# Объединение объектов класса С++

Tags: c++, классы, объекты, объединение

Нужна помощь с выполнением задания:

> Создать класс-однонаправленный список с элементами типа char.
>   Перегрузить операции: объединение списков, доступ к элементу по
>   номеру, проверка на равенство.

Конкретно с первым "Объединение списка" у меня проблема. Остальное я реализовал.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

class Element {
public:
    char data;

    Element *next;
    Element() {
        next = NULL;
    }
};

class Spisok {
private:
    Element *head;
    int size;
public:
    Spisok() {
        head = new Element();
        head->data = NULL;
        size = 0;
    }

    void AddToStart(char d) {
        if (head->data == NULL) {
            head->data = d;
            size++;
        }
        else {
            Element * temp = new Element();
            temp->data = d;
            temp->next = head;
            head = temp;
            size++;
        }
    }

    void AddToStart(Element *el) {
        if (head->data == NULL) {
            head->data = el->data;
            size++;
        }
        else {
            Element * temp = new Element();
            temp->data = el->data;
            temp->next = head;
            head = temp;
            size++;
        }
    }               

    Element * Get(int n) {
        if (n < size) {
            if (n == 0) {
                Element * temp = head;
                return temp;
            }
            else {
                Element * temp = head->next;
                for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
                    temp = temp->next;
                }
                return temp;
            }
        }
        else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    void getn(int i) {
        Element *temp1;
        temp1 = Get(i);
        cout << temp1->data <<endl;
    }

    bool Ravenstvo(Spisok * spis2) {
        Element *temp1, *temp2;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            temp1 = Get(i);
            temp2 = spis2->Get(i);
            if (temp1->data != temp2->data) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }        

    void Show() {
        Element * temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL) {
            cout << temp->data << " ";
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    cout << "1-st spisok" << endl;
    Spisok *spis1 = new Spisok();
    spis1->AddToStart('a');
    spis1->AddToStart('b');
    spis1->AddToStart('c');
    spis1->Show();

    spis1->getn(0);

    spis1->DelFromStart();
    spis1->Show();

    cout << "2-nd spisok" << endl;
    Spisok *spis2 = new Spisok();
    Element * el1 = new Element();
    el1->data = 'd';
    Element * el2 = new Element();
    el2->data = 'e';
    Element * el3 = new Element();
    el3->data = 'f';

    spis2->AddToStart(el1);
    spis2->AddToStart(el2);
    spis2->AddToStart(el3);
    spis2->Show(); 

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Добавил такой кусок.
   char str(int i){
  Element *temp1;
  temp1 = Get(i);
  return temp1->data;
}

 void AddTo(Spisok * spis2){
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
  if (head->data == NULL){
   head->data = spis2->str(i);
   size++;
  }
  else{
   Element * temp = new Element();
   temp->data = spis2->str(i);;
   temp->next = head;
   head = temp;
   size++;
  }}
 }   
Но он добавляет зеркально((( То-есть qwe+asd=ewqasd

Comment: А где в классе Вы перегружаете обозначенные операторы? operator = , operator +=, operator +, operator[], operator ==